# do-release-upgrade from LTS to newer (but not newest!) LTS

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, 16.04, upgrade, lts

I have a server running 12.04 LTS and I'd like to upgrade it to 14.04 LTS. When I try to run do-release-upgrade -c, it shows that the command would update the system to 16.04 LTS instead. I read the post at [do-release-upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 instead of 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769930/do-release-upgrade-from-12-04-to-14-04-instead-of-16-04) and the answers basically don't apply here.

The system is in the cloud and I only have SSH access.

Moving to 16.04 would be mean a significant overhaul of the application based on supported software, and isn't really an option.

Is there any way to use do-release-upgrade to upgrade an LTS system to a newer (but not newest) LTS version?

Is my only option to install 14.04 fresh?

Thanks!

---

Update. This is my sources list (http:// removed):
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe

Comment: Have a look at the answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/769930/do-release-upgrade-from-12-04-to-14-04-instead-of-16-04 - maybe it is still valid. And first try `do-release-upgrade -c` to see what would be done.

Comment: do-release-upgrade -c, as stated in the question, points to 16.04

Comment: What's the output of `lsb_relase -a` and `grep -vEe '^\s*$|#|precise' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`?

Comment: Hi David - the lsb_release command returns: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty